# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet is not recognizing worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import a sheet from an Excel workbook using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.  The sheet's name is `XYZ Priority`.

I'm calling the method as follows:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet FileName:=filePath, tablename:="XYZ", _
                          hasfieldnames:=True, range:="[XYZ Priority]!"
```

I get this error message:

```
'[XYZ Priority]$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not 
include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.
```

It appears that the space is what's causing the problem.  I've tried several different ways to identify the range, with and without exclamation points, and all have failed:

```
"XYZ Priority"
"XYZ_Priority"
"'XYZ Priority'"
```

How can I correctly pass the sheet to `TransferSpreadsheet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use just the sheet name followed by the `$` sign.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet FileName:=filePath, TableName:="XYZ", _
    HasFieldNames:=True, Range:="XYZ Priority$"
```