# How can I select a specific sheet from an Excel file to import into Access?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

[image]

In the image I show the interface through which I select the Excel file to import.

It works perfect as long as you enter the name of the sheet in the code:

`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "MYSTERY_SHOPPER", fileName, True, "Junio-2019!"`

However, I would like the user to select the sheet they want to import (perhaps with an inputbox to capture the name of the sheet?) since he should not enter each time and edit that line.

SOLVED - Thaks to @June7

```
'----------------- BUTTON BROWSE

Private Sub btnbuscar_Click()

Dim diag2 As Office.FileDialog
Dim Item2 As Variant

Set diag2 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
diag2.AllowMultiSelect = False
diag2.Title = "Choose a Excel file"
diag2.Filters.Clear
diag2.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls, *.xlsx"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

If diag2.Show Then
    For Each Item2 In diag2.SelectedItems
        Me.etiquetaarchivo = Item2
    Next
End If

End Sub


'---------------- BUTTON IMPORT

Private Sub btnimportar_Click()

Dim FSO2 As New FileSystemObject

If Nz(Me.etiquetaarchivo, "") = "" Then
    MsgBox "You don't select a file!"
    Exit Sub
End If

If FSO2.FileExists(Nz(Me.etiquetaarchivo, "")) Then

    ExcelImport2.ImportExcelSpreadsheet Me.etiquetaarchivo, FSO2.GetFileName(Me.etiquetaarchivo)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Else
    MsgBox "Not file found!"
End If


'---------------- MODULE

Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)
On Error GoTo BadFormat

Dim Hoja As String
Hoja = inputbox("Input the sheet name")
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "MYSTERY_SHOPPER", fileName, True, Hoja & "$"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Exit Sub

BadFormat:
    MsgBox "The format isn't correct"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not simply add another box to the form you show where the user can enter the sheet name?

Comment: @urdearboy I think the interface (form and code) is in Access, so they won't be able to use `Application.Input`...

Comment: @undearboy Cindy is correct, all the code is in Access

Comment: @Cindy I'm beginner in Access VBA, can u help me with the another box? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you not create the form in the screen shot at the top yourself?

Comment: I refer to the encoding to capture the selected file sheet in the first form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet is not recognizing worksheet name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350789/docmd-transferspreadsheet-is-not-recognizing-worksheet-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate user textbox input with $ character in Range argument.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "MYSTERY_SHOPPER", fileName, True, Me.tbxSheet & "$"
```

If you want to specify range as well as sheet, syntax is:

`"SheetName!A1:E10"`

Or with range name

`"SheetName!MyRange"`